# Ajax, Bonfire calling a controller function from a view

Tags: bonfire

I am trying to call a controller function using ajax after clicking a button in a view. I am using Bonfire but there is no response at all. I need guidance. Below is my JQuery/Ajax code placed in a js file in the assets folder of one of my modules.

```
var base_url = '<? base_url()?>';
$('.tes_btn').click(function(){

     var html_data = $(".admin-box").html();

        $.ajax({
             url: base_url + "test_module/reports/domPdfTest",  
             type: "POST", 
             data:"html_data="+ html_data,
             success:function(result){   
           // alert('Good work');
        }
    });
});
```

the controller function looks like this

```
function domPdfTest(){

    $dompdf = new DOMPDF();
    $html = $this->input->post('html_data');
    $this->dompdf->load_html($html);
    $this->dompdf->render();
    $this->dompdf->stream("test_report.pdf");
}
```

I Load the following in the constructor of my controller

```
$this->load->library('dompdf_gen');
Assets::add_module_js('test_module', 'test_module.js');
```

and my view button looks like this

```
<input type="button" id="tes_btn" value="tes btn" class="tes_btn"></input>
```

Is there anything am missing? Thanks in advance..Judas

Comment: Judas, did you check that your urls are correctly set?

Comment: Dear Lajos, not very certain. Have used trial and error. I at-least expected an Error alert like "wrong url"..but no response at all. What do I do?

Comment: console.log(base_url + "test_module/reports/domPdfTest") should give you the path you are requesting. How is that look like?

Comment: Okay...have tested it, but still shows no response. How can we provoke some kind of response to test the AJax?

Comment: Let me get you the url

Comment: POST http://localhost/lims/public/index.php/admin/reports/cash_crops_grown     ....it shows after I have clicked. I also see Status Code:  HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: I believe it should start with http://, so try this: url: "http://" + base_url + "test_module/reports/domPdfTest"

Comment: using chrom inspector:  http://<? base_url()?>cash_crops_grown/reports/domPdfTest ....this is wrong..so

Comment: No, you have tested it the wrong way. Can you put the console.log call I have given you just before your request?

Comment: I modified my function to $('.tes_btn').click(function(){
   var html_data = $(".admin-box").html();
  console.log("http://"+ base_url + "cash_crops_grown/reports/domPdfTest") ;   
  //$.ajax({
   //  url: console.log(base_url + "cash_crops_grown/reports/domPdfTest") ,   
   //  type: "POST", 
   //  data:"html_data="+ html_data,
   // success:function(result){  
  // // alert('Good work');
  //}
  //});
});

Comment: Can you tell me what was the result of the console.log?

Comment: http://<? base_url()?>cash_crops_grown/reports/domPdfTest ...it is not being parsed when I click on the button in a view. am using an external js file in the assets folder...I need to reference the url the right way in the js file

Comment: The <? base_url()?> part is the problem, so your base_url is not initialized properly, that is your problem.

Comment: yeah...that is very true...so how can I reference the base_url from the js file?

Comment: Please, read my answer

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
var base_url = '<? base_url()?>';
```

try this:

```
var base_url = "http://" + window.location.host + "/";
```

`window.location.host` holds the host except the `http://` part.

Comment: yeah, this is good. The url seems fine now as generated by console.log http://localhost/cash_crops_grown/reports/domPdfTest ...clicking the button shows a 404; POST http://localhost/cash_crops_grown/reports/domPdfTest 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Can you describe the path of your domPdfTest file? Does it have an extension? Do you have some rewrite rules in .htaccess which enables this kind of access?

Comment: oooh, domPdfTest is a function in a controller called reports (as described in the question). I am calling that function...the url should look like this  http://localhost/lims/public/index.php/admin/reports/cash_crops_grown/domPdfTest

Comment: Then this: test_module/reports/domPdfTest is not a valid url. How do you want to tell the server that you want to call that function? Through GET, or POST parameters? Or something else?

Comment: Using POST parameter. In this case, cash_crops_grown is the module. Within domPdfTest I have the line of code $html = $this->input->post('html_data'); which should capture posted data from ajax. The url is the main issue

Comment: Then why don't you try it with: url: base_url + "lims/public/index.php/admin/reports/cash_crops_grown/domPdfTest". I am helping you based on the information you give me. If you describe your problem clearly, then it is easier for me to help you.

Comment: I indeed appreciate your help. Testing it directly gives a 404;  POST http://localhost/lims/public/index.php/admin/reports/lims/public/index.php/admin/reports/cash_crops_grown/domPdfTest 404 (Not Found)... is it possible we can connect on skype or use team viewer? am certain this will help alot..my skype username is jt-judas..thanks alot

Comment: I am in the middle of something, I cannot chat right now, but I believe you need to refer to http://localhost/lims/public/index.php/admin/reports/lims/public/index.php It seems that the additional content after the .php is the mistake and I believe you need to post to index.php and pass the needed post parameters inside data.

Comment: Okay thanks for your time, I will keep trying and will post my final solution.

Comment: You are welcome, best of luck with your problem and I wish you a happy new year

Comment: Thanks, and happy new year to you too.

Comment: the right URL is being obtained now using  url: window.location + "/domPdfTest",  ...looking at console, it generates Internal server error: POST http://localhost/lims/public/index.php/admin/reports/cash_crops_grown/domPdfTest [HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error 15ms]...any advice here? thanks in advance